# How define array to fit negative indexes?

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write function which will return correct string when I will pass error in its argument. But it's not clear to me how to assign negative indexes to strings (corresponding to enum FILE_ERRORS_t), can you clarify?

```
typedef enum {
    FOPEN_ERROR=-1,
    FREAD_ERROR=-2,
    FWRITE_ERROR=-3,
    FSEEK_ERROR=-4,
    FCLOSE_ERROR=-5
    } FILE_ERRORS_t;
#define printErr (const char*[5]){"Cannot open file", "Cannot read file", "Cannot write file", "fseek fail", "fclose fail" }
```

Comment: Reverse the `enum`. Now use index `[ERROR+5]`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make an array that takes negative indexes, but you can make a pointer to the middle of an array so that when you combine it with a negative index, you get a valid element of a "regular" C array. Here is how:

```
static char * real_errors[] = {
    "fclose fail"       // -5
,   "fseek fail"        // -4
,   "Cannot write file" // -3
,   "Cannot read file"  // -2
,   "Cannot open file"  // -1
};
static char **errors = &real_errors[5]; // Point one element past the end
```

Now you can write this:

```
printf("%s\n", errors[FCLOSE_ERROR]);
```

and it would work, because it is equivalent to

```
printf("%s\n", real_errors[5+FCLOSE_ERROR]);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/F3RwDu)

**Note:** This is only well-defined if errors is pointing inside the array or one past the end. Otherwise, it would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, please go ahead teaching people to obsfucate their sources ... |-S

Comment: @alk Once they *know* the trick, it no longer counts as obfuscation. This one in particular is very useful for understanding relations of pointers and arrays, even if they never use it in real life.

Comment: Ok for educational purpose ... - fair enough ;-)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that, technically, this is only well-defined if `errors` is pointing inside the array or one past the end. If the error codes were -6 through -2, the analogous solution would technically be undefined behavior!

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the absolute value as described [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/abs.php) and then subtracting one. Then -1 will become 0, -2 will become 1, etc. That should map as you want it to. So the function might looks something like this:

```
int errorCodeToIndex(FILE_ERRORS_t errorCode) {
    return abs(errorCode) - 1
```

You may need to convert `errorCode` to an int and remember to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative index reversing the order of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    FOPEN_ERROR=-1,
    FREAD_ERROR=-2,
    FWRITE_ERROR=-3,
    FSEEK_ERROR=-4,
    FCLOSE_ERROR=-5
    } FILE_ERRORS_t;

#define sup ((const char *[]){"fclose fail", "fseek fail", "Cannot write file" ,"Cannot read file", "Cannot open file", ""} + 5)

int main(void)
{
    puts(sup[FSEEK_ERROR]);
    return 0;
}
```

Ouptut:

```
fseek fail
```

Comment: Even more obsfucation, however I love compound statements ...! ;-) 1+

Answer (score 1):

Just use a function-like macro and designated initializers

```
#define printErr(E) (const char*const[]){[-FOPEN_ERROR] = "Cannot open file", ... }[-E]
```

This makes the array as large as needed and ensures that each string is place at the correct position in it.